# Why does React JS UI Components tests matter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

I want to layout an example, before asking the question:

You create a reactjs app, and have a site with a header at top, a section below header and then at the bottom we have a footer. The code will look something like this:

```html
<header>...</header>
<section>...</section>
<footer>...</footer>
```

Now, the question why it is worth testing these ui components?

I am not able to understand, why we test resultant HTML of the webpage, because it it not going to break our site, or improve our app in any way, on the other side it makes sense to test the backend of the app, or we can test some functions that perform some calculations, because it makes sense to test them, as they will be responsible for filling the html skeleton with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're asking, but correct me if I am wrong.

So, from a user's perspective, they do not care what the components are as long as they see what they expect to see, so I understand where you're coming from when it comes to testing that `header` renders `header` etc. This, in itself, provides little value - although from an accessibility point of view, testing that your markup is semantic could be argued as a reason to test that kind of thing.

The question I'd be asking myself when testing the above is - what is the functionality that my user is expecting? You mentioned testing the backend - but what about testing the frontend functionality that triggers the backend code - for example, testing that when a button is clicked a request is made to the API the backend is providing?

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a simple website alone with React, then yes, there is no point to test it.

But if you start to add complex stuff, such as a component having a component and it is inside another component, or using libraries such as Redux, it is hard to keep track of the changes and guaranteed they are bug-free when you change any one of them, especially when you are working with a team.

Libraries such as Jest allows you to mock and test each component individually, by setting up tests with edge cases that covers all components, it allows to "simulate the user interactions" and see does it meet the expected results. Which you can say "Ok, this change is bug-free if it passed all the tests, so I can push the change without worry breaking other stuff that was working"

At the end, the user/client does not care how you build it, they only care if they can see the button or if the button is working or not, and if you make a change that leads to the button not working, they will be mad at you.